# SQL ServerReporting Services - Export report to PDF

Tags: c#, asp.net, reporting-services

I have a report which has a document map for navigation. When I export it to PDF, the document map becomes "Bookmarks" which I can navigate from Adobe Reader. All good, but I need two ectra features:

1. In addition to the Bookmarks I need a classic table of contents with page numbers and navigation links.
2. I want the Bookmarks side  windows to be oipenend by default when I view the PDF file. I know this can be done in Adobe Acrobat Professional, and it is a PDF file flag. But I would like to achieve this when I export the PDF programatically.

Thank you very much.

You can contact me on my private email address: voiku.manuel@gmail.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the link for PDF Documentation (RS 2008) 
- http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd255291%28SQL.105%29.aspx
This has all of the options available to creating a PDF in RS 2008. Including Bookmarks